# How to properly cite Donald Knuth’s The Art of Computer Programming?

Tags: citing

How should I go about citing Donald Knuth’s famous monograph? I have two use cases:

- Citing a single page,
- citing multiple consecutive pages.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If I recall correctly, there are currently five completed volumes in the TAOCP series: Volumes 1, 2, 3, 4A, and 4B. (According to information on [amazon.com](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201038064), Volume 4B was published earlier this month -- Oct. 2022.) Let's assume you have entries for all five volumes in your bib file and that these entries have keys `taocp1`, `taocp2`, `taocp3`, `taocp4a`,  and `taocp4b`, respectively. (My apologies for not being very imaginative with naming conventions.)

Then all you have to do to get the desired citation call-out is to make sure that your document loads a suitable citation management package -- e.g., [cite](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/cite) or [natbib](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/natbib) -- so that you can write

```
\cite[p.~55]{taocp1}
```

and

```
\cite[pp.\ 90--102]{taocp3}
```

If numeric-style citation call-outs are needed, then both `cite` and `natbib` will do. (Be sure to load the latter package with the option `numbers`.) If you need authoryear-style citation call-outs, you should employ the `natbib` package with the option `authoryear`.